# How can I delate data from firebase with AND statement

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

DELETE/ SELECT * FROM Product WHERE code = typedValue AND userId = currentUser

[firebase look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSjMx.png)

I have this but this is like SELECT * FROM Product WHERE code = typedValue

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
query = ref.child("Product").orderByChild("code").equalTo(typedValue);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasChildren()){
            for(DataSnapshot codeSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                codeSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
            }
            Toast.makeText(AbcActivity.this, "Delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(AbcActivity.this, "This product is not available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Firebase doesn't support DELETE/UPDATE queries, where you send both the condition and the action to the server. You'll need to execute the query in your application code to determine the affected node(s) and then update each of them individually, as the code you shared seems to be doing. What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The code works, but different users may have the product with the same code. So I can remove a product with the same code added by another user

Comment: Ah, so does this boil down to: how can I perform a query on two fields? Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase. The only alternative is to perform the additional filter in your application code, so checking the UID inside the loop in `onDataChange`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you very much.